# hadoop commands run manually but in cron don't run

Tags: shell, ubuntu, hadoop

I'am trying to execute shell script that run my hadoop jobs periodically,i put my script in crontab  but all hadoop commands don't run .
When i execute my script shell manually (from cli ) hadoop commands run normally 
i'am using ubuntu 14.04

Comment: If the cluster is kerberized cluster, the ticket expiry may create issues else, check the path is available for the cron.

Comment: actually i'm new in hadoop so i didn't understand what ot means "kerberized cluster" , concerning the path i have put the absolute path to the script:
bash /home/hduser/Desktop/myscript.sh

Comment: Ok fine. As which user your cron is running ?

Comment: it's running with user called hduser

Comment: Is hadoop command working from hduser. Can you share the script that you used in cron

Comment: yes hadoop command is running from hduser and even my script which contains these hadoop commands run when i execute it manually ,it 's not running only when i put the script in cron

Answer (score 3):

If you see that the script executes normal on terminal, and fails when you execute through the cron, then the problem might be mostly because of the environmental differences between the terminal and cron env.

The problem could be because of the `PATH` variable by which you were directly invoking the `hadoop` command, which might be not fully conveyed to the cron env.

My suggestion is to use the **absolute path**(full path) of the `hadoop` command in your shell script. You find the full path of the hadoop command by executing the `which hadoop` from your terminal.

Please refer the below link regarding the above env issue.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Mncf Nsr, were you able fix this?

Comment: yes it worked when i have put th absolute path of the hadoop command thx

Comment: i can't because i have less than 15 reputation :(

Comment: thx :) trust me, when i will have the privilage to vote i will vote alll ur answers :))

Answer (score 0):

I have also same issue with cron ..